# ruby on rails psychometric app

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, survey

Guys.

I'm trying to create a ruby on rails app that will allow a user to answer a set of questions for a psychometric assessment.

An example of a question is: `I am driven by financial reward`. 
The answers are multiple choice: `strongly disagree; disagree; neutral; agree; strongly agree`. The answers need to be weighted so each answer must have a numerical value 1-5 so the answers average can be calculated.

Has anyone built a similar app with a repo I could see how you went about it? or any tips on where to look? I am new to development.

Comment: "or any tips on where to look" - it depends on what you're having problems with. Don't know how to even start? I'd start with a ruby/rails book and/or online course.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Create the custom form and when the user hits the submit `server-side` you do the calculate and write your logic there.

```
UserController < ActiveRecord::Base
 ..... 

 def psychometric_assessment #Define routes to call this method
   ****YOUR LOGIC***** 
 end 

 .....

end
```

Comment: There is no `User` model in the app as of now. Why `UsersController`? :)

Comment: @JagdeepSingh, why `UsersController` but not why `Controller < ActiveRecord::Base`? :)

Comment: Wow. Never saw that. :D

Comment: This got accepted? what?